# Model in TypeScript returns as an object not as model

Tags: angular, typescript

in my angular app in my component I use .subscribe with model when get the model from storage.

```
.subscribe((tradeModel: TradeModel) => {
  if (tradeModel !== null && tradeModel !== undefined) {
    console.log(this.dragMoveTrade) // model;
    console.log(tradeModel) // object;
    console.log(tradeModel.Stage) // 2 (number);
  }
```

As you can see I use `TradeModel` in my subscribe obj. I can get for example from it any property. For example

```
`console.log(tradeModel.Stage)` ==> 2
```

But I can't set any value to any property. If I try

```
tradeModel.Stage = 3
```

I have an exeption

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'Stage' of object '[object Object]'
```

I have property in component `dragMoveTrade: TradeModel = new TradeModel();`

if I print both of them

```
console.log(this.dragMoveTrade);
console.log(tradeModel);
```

I see that this.dragMoveTrade is a real `TradeModel`. tradeModel only an object. Screenshot below

[image]

for this model I can change any property

```
this.dragMoveTrade.Stage = 3
```

Why my `.subscribe` with model return an object. Not a model or how I can convert it to the model?

class of TradeModel.

```
export class TradeModel {
public TradeId: string;
public ClientId: string;
public UserId: string;
public Stage: number;
}
```

Comment: please share the contents of trade model interface!

Comment: just out of curiosity, are you using in your project a state management tool such as ngRx? or redux? or ngxs?

Comment: I use ngrx and get data from selector.

Comment: @NarenMurali All property in TradeModel are public. I edit the post and add the class of model

Comment: @FX_Sektor, any changes you would want to make to the data returned from the `selector` in your component, you will need to handle that in the `store`, that is why the readonly message.

Comment: Since you are using ngrx, I don't recommend `subscribe`ing to the selector **manually**, instead let the template HTML handle the data by using `async` pipe. If you think is not necessary to handle the data modification of tradeModel in the store, then create a copy of it in the component like `copy = {...this.tradeModel};` and then re-assign that copy back tot the original tradeModel whenever you finished modifying the copy value

Comment: @Andres2142 Thanks. I think It is a decision. Now I can modify the value. By the way - I need only do some modification in ts code, so I need`t to use async pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why my .subscribe with model return an object. Not a model or how I can convert it to the model?

As you wrote it in the comments, you are using ngrx for state management. In this particular case, when you select the data from the store, it returns the data as readonly, following the related [redux principle](https://www.educative.io/courses/building-teslas-battery-range-calculator-with-react-and-redux/2-5-redux-three-principles) (see 2.5.2).

---

If you would like to modify the data, you have to modify your effect (if you have one), or maybe do it in the reducer. Both of these can lead to hard-to-understand code, since under the hood something magical happens.

If you would like to do this by any cost, and you would like to do it in the given component, you can configure ngrx to not have those strict immutability checks.

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
  runtimeChecks: {
    strictStateImmutability: false,
    strictActionImmutability: false,
  },
}),
```

This will affect the whole application (if you dont have subsequent stores).
I think the best way would be to dispatch another action, when you model is there (the fetch has been finished), to modify it - if you would like to update your model at all.